# Ubuntu 14.04 gets stuck at shutdown

Tags: 14.04

My girlfriend's laptop seems to have another problem with Ubuntu. Apparently, it gets stuck at shutdown. It has never happend to me, when I tried it. It happens just to her (but that is OK, computers are afraid of me). It hangs on Ubuntu logo with those 3 dots below it. Are there any logs, that could help me (and you) to find out, what is the problem?